# google sheet add button to insert new row that has formula

Tags: google-sheets

This is the simplified version of my data. I want to place a button at the bottom of the grey area, so that upon clicking, a new row is inserted above the bottom. the new row must have the formula as the rows before it.

[image]
my real formulas are very complicated so I cant use arrayFormula to fulfill the data in new rows.
[this a link to my spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aXJ1jdLLYTw4Z3bW65S062rX4TPwRKd3-PSWg3C2eVE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Be aware that if you insert a row, the formula below will likely be wrong, like in column B of your worksheet.

Comment: @MikeSteelson Can you send your suggestion as an answer or in the sheet?

Comment: ok, done ... now, I will be very curious to find a solution by arrayformula even in a complex one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this sample code that uses a custom menu to insert new row with formula based on the previous row.

### Code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Insert New Row', 'insertRow')
      .addToUi();
}

function insertRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();

  //Exit function if current active sheet is not Sheet1
  if(sheet.getName() != "Sheet1"){
    return;
  }

  //insert new row
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow,2,1,3).copyTo(sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2));
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the last row  and the last column that has content in the active sheet using [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) and [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)
2. Insert a new row after the last row that has content using [insertRowAfter(afterPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowafterafterposition)
3. Get the range of the last row that has content using [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Where:

`row` = your last row that has content

`column` = column index where you want to start (in the sample sheet it is in column B/ index 2)

`numRows` = should be 1 (we only want to copy the current last row that has content)

`numCols` = how many columns to select. In the sample sheet there are 3 columns (column B-D)

4. Use [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) to copy both values and formatting of the range selected in step 3 and paste it in the newly added row. Destination range should be the top-left cell. Since we want to copy it to the new row.I used `getRange(last row +1, 2)`

### Output:

[image]

### Note:

- If you want to use button placed below the grey row, just use `insertRow` when you assign a script in your button
- Please make sure that the last row with content is the row that has formula.

---

If you want to use the function on a specified list of sheets, you can add this in the sample code. This will exit the function if the current active sheet name is not included in the valid sheets listed

```
  var validSheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];

  if(!validSheets.includes(sheet.getName())){
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue so i could update the answer accordingly

Comment: My Google-sheet might have multiple sheets. How can I restrict this function to only insert in the specified sheet?

Comment: I updated the answer to add sheet name checking. Just replace `Sheet1` with your specified sheet name

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comment ... then click on the new menu : this script will add a new line in the active sheet

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('>> Action <<')
    .addItem('Copy last row (formulas only)', 'copyLastRow')
    .addToUi();
}
function copyLastRow() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var rng=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn())
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false)
}
```